# Expectation Value of Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation, linear-algebra

In the book Modern Quantum Mechanics by Sakurai the expectation value of A is defined as
$$ \left <A\right> = \left<\psi\right|A\left|\psi\right>$$
And, we can also write it as (as provided in the book),
$$  \left <A\right> = \sum_{a'}\sum_{a''}\left<\alpha|a''\right> \left<a''|A|a'\right> \left<a'|\alpha\right>$$
and after this equation, they directly write this equation as,
$$ =\sum_{a'}a' \left|\right< a'|\alpha\left>\right|^{2} $$
and I want to understand the algebra behind it, so the only step that I was able to figure out is,
$$  \left <A\right> = \sum_{a'}\sum_{a''}\left<\alpha|a''\right> a'\delta_{a',a''}\left<a'|\alpha\right>$$
where $\delta_{a',a''}$ is kronecker delta. Can you help me out on how they reached to the final step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you just need to enforce the $\delta$ so that $\sum_{a''}\langle \alpha | a''\rangle \delta_{a'',a'} = \langle \alpha | a'\rangle$

Then you have:
$$\langle \alpha | a'\rangle \langle a'| \alpha \rangle  =  |\langle a'| \alpha \rangle|^2 $$